# Dynamically populating the manual intervention message

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In my release pipeline I want to dynamically populate the message box that shows up for a manual intervention. The use case is like so:

I have a *manual* test plan that I would like the stage approver to refer to before giving his/her approval. I want to populate the manual intervention message box with a link to the specific Manual Test Plan's test run chart in AzDo portal.

Since this is dynamic information, how can I apply the message to the manual intervention message box dynamically at release creation workflow execution time.

Comment: You could use a azure function to create the message, and update the task with the Azure DevOps API. Let me try to do it, and hopefully will give you a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63436796/how-to-get-approver-details-using-manual-interventions-task-in-classic-release-p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be achieved. Azure release pipeline does not support this feature to populate message box currently.

You can [submit a feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(Click Suggest a Feature and Choose Azure Devops) to Microsoft Development team. Hope they will consider implement this feature in the future.