# How to get Approver details using Manual Interventions task in classic release pipeline using REST API

Tags: azure, api, rest, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I found Manual Interventions - Get https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/manual%20interventions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#manualinterventionstatus
with GET-https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseId}/manualinterventions/{manualInterventionId}?api-version=5.1

this as REST API to get the details, but the issue is, m not able to find/determine the '**manualInterventionId**' in this API. I created release pipeline, set pre-deployment approver details in it, but can someone tell me the exact flow to get Approver details using Manual Interventions task in classic release pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get Approver details using Manual Interventions task in classic release pipeline using REST API

To get the `manualInterventionId` for the REST API `Manual Interventions - Get`, we could use the REST API `Manual Interventions - List` to list all manual interventions for a given release.

[**Manual Interventions - List**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/manual%20interventions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseId}/manualinterventions?api-version=5.1
```

Then we could get all manual interventions:

[image]

Now, we could use the Id with REST API Manual Interventions - Get:

[image]